# separate fontsize in string and number; with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have an string

'10px'
or
'1.5em'

i need to separate it with lodash, (and maybe regex) and get this values:

```
10
px
```

or

```
1.5
em
```

I've tried with this:

```
import words from 'lodash';
let cc= words([v],/(\d+)/);
```

but it does not work,  any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with regex in the following way

```js
let fontsize = '10px';

console.log(fontsize.match(/(\d+)(\w+)/));
```

you will get the values in the 1st and 2nd index

Comment: thanks, i've tried with react, but i get : TypeError: v.match is not a function, same when i want to use split

Comment: I realize my probleme i have {normal: "1em"} , where the key  can be different, how to get the second part in this object ?

Comment: sorry your answer it's right but my scenario was different, i have an object

Comment: sorry last favour, my size can be points, can you adapt the regex ? please

Comment: i've found the solution with this: .match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)(\w+)/);